# Psfrag does not replace the tag more than one symbol

Tags: psfrag

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{figure}
    \psfrag{e}{$e$}
    \psfrag{w1}{$w_1$}
    \psfrag{w2}{$w_2$}
    \psfrag{v1}{$v_1$}
    \psfrag{v2}{$v_2$}
    \psfrag{v3}{$v_3$}
    \psfrag{v4}{$v_4$}
    \psfrag{eL1}{$e^L_1$}
    \psfrag{eR1}{$e^R_1$}
    \psfrag{eL2}{$e^L_2$}
    \psfrag{a}{$\Rightarrow$}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{eps_hw2_binaryToTri.eps}
\end{figure}
```

I compile my .tex file in WinEdt 10.2 in PDFTeXify with `dvi -> ps -> pdf`, but it only change the tag with single symbol. How can I replace the tags with more than one symbol?

[image]

Comment: as documented in the psfrag package documentation whether or not psfrag can "see" multi-letter strings depends on the details of the application producing the original image. If it "typesets" the strings adding spacing adjustments between letters (as tex would) then a string such as `eL1` may not be in the file, but rather three separate strings `e`, `L` and `1` with spacing, in which case psfrag will fail to find the string `eL1` as it is not there...

Comment: Oh.. I created this image in Adobe Illustrator. Where can I find relevant settings?

Comment: I have no idea about adobe illustrator, but if you look in the file and do not see a literal string `(eL1)` then psfrag will not see it either.  You might get away with replacing w by `$w$` `L` by `$^L$` and 1-9 by `$_1$`.. `$_9$`  Or just redo the labels in illustrator in a different font or different options, or just with single letters.....

Comment: putting `psfrag adobe illustrator` into google shows http://gglanzani.tumblr.com/post/1649264221/illustrator-and-psfrag

Comment: It Works! The key was saving EPS for _Version_ the _Illustrator3_.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psfrag can only replace strings that appear as literal strings in the PostScript, if you use a typesetting application that adds kerns, so positions each letter individually then multi-letter strings get split up.

The details to avoid this depend on the application, using single letter strings usually works but is not very convenient. or sometimes using digits or a monospace font avoids kerning issues.

Or for Adobe illustrator saving in a format compatible with an old enough version (apparently it has a save option to be compatible with version 3)
works in most cases.