# Using psfrag with Adobe Illustrator

Tags: psfrag

I'm trying to make psfrag work with EPS files created by Adobe Illustrator.
It seems like no matter what option I use for Adobe Illustrator, my text always comes embedded inside the file.

I've tried saving the file using Illustrator 3 EPS, as suggested [here](https://engineeringrevision.com/314/getting-illustrator-to-play-nicely-with-psfrag/), but it doesn't seem to work as well.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: psfrag can only replace strings that appear as a single string in the eps. You can test by using single letters in the original file rather than replacing long strings.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358792/psfrag-does-not-replace-the-tag-more-than-one-symbol/358912#358912

Comment: if your original texts are letterspaced see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289048/cant-get-psfrag-to-replace-text-in-pdf/289243#289243 (but if they are single letter that shouldn't be an issue